# npm install questions, run into some problems

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js

I run this for first time:

npm install and get this:

```
npm WARN engine laravel-mix@0.8.9: wanted: {"node":">=6.0.0"} (current:         {"node":"4.4.7","npm":"2.15.8"})
npm WARN engine webpack-dev-server@2.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=4.7"} (current: {"node":"4.4.7","npm":"2.15.8"})
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.1.1
```

What can I do about these warnings? How do I upgrade to what it wants?

My package.json

  `"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"`

Comment: Upgrade your version of node, it says so right in the warnings.

Comment: after I update node should I run npm install again? right now it has installed lots of stuff

Answer (score 2):

Update nodejs, run `npm cache clear`, delere `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`

Comment: ok thanks, I am running on win10 and have gitbash, what can I do about this message: npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator. is that important at all? It seems that its trying to rename some folders, got any suggestion for this?

Comment: Run as Administrator Git Bash or you can simply run this commands from cmd, the you need just to be inside the project folder